# JSON response is int but string when empty

Tags: go

I am unmarshalling a JSON response into a struct. For one of the fields, it returns an int and a string when empty.

```
type example struct {    
  Position int `json:"position"`
}

json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field .position of type int
```

The response is either

```
{"position":8} or {"position":"none"}
```

How can I handle both an int and string response?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number Tip: Always read the whole package documentation.

Comment: If the `position` field in the JSON, is always inside double quote (like `"18"`) then just change the tag to `json:"position,string"`. Otherwise you have to implement UnmarshalJSON method.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll look into those options

Comment: @KavehShahbazian yes it is double quoted, still getting the message when adding your suggestion

Comment: @1mmerse I was wrong. I did not pay enough attention the the other value is `"none"` and not `""`. This can only be implemented by writing a `UnmarshalJSON` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type to `interface{}`, and then you can check the type at runtime.

```
type example struct {    
    Position interface{} `json:"position"`
}
/*
Returns an int and a bool, indicating if a position exists.
*/
func (e * example) getValue() (int,bool){
    if v,ok := Position.(int) {
      return v,true
    } else {
     return 0,false
    }
}
```